# Automate website login process using selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to login to a website using selenium webdriver and excel VBA but im getting stuck at the log in page

im using the following code:

```vb
Dim bot As New WebDriver

bot.Start "chrome", "myurl"
bot.Get "/"

'select from drop down
bot.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlRoleType").AsSelect.SelectByValue "7"

bot.FindElementById("MainContent_UserName").SendKeys "userid"
bot.FindElementById("MainContent_Password").SendKeys "password"

'select from drop down
bot.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlAuxCentre").AsSelect.SelectByValue "1"

bot.FindElementById("MainContent_LogOnButton").SendKeys bot.Keys.Enter
```

all data is entered properly till the log in button is clicked which produces the following error message:

> The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +11320030
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

Comment: Does this login work manually? It may be an error on your server you're executing against.

Comment: yes it works perfectly when i do it manually

Comment: that's a server-side error that usually happens when too much data is sent via GET.  Post the HTML for the page of the form.

Comment: Shot in the dark since I'm not familiar with VBA, but is the error different if you `Click`(Typical) vs send `Keys.Enter`?   `bot.FindElementById("MainContent_LogOnButton").Click`

Comment: No click produces the same error.

Comment: https://www.XXXXXXXX.in/XXXX/(S(cebetkvcfbert45c2h4vu42j))/home.aspx i hope its ok to not post the name of the website here

Comment: It was a server side error a shortened url lead me to the same page so the problem was fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a server side error a shortened url lead me to the same page so the problem was fixed. Thanks. –